# Dynamically resolve Promise.all responses for each API call and store data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm passing right now 3 API calls to Promise.all. For now for each API call i need to create separate Error handler and if data is being return store to it's own object (corresponding to same API object name).

If i pass `test4` to Promise.all how can i make it generate it's own error and storing data to state object, instead of my manually adding those values?

I have tried loop the response but getting `Object { test3: Promise { "fulfilled" } }` and no data.

Code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'

const getTest1 = Promise.resolve({ isData: true, isError: false })
const getTest2 = Promise.resolve({ isData: false, isError: true })
const getTest3 = Promise.resolve({ isData: true, isError: false })

export const PromiseAll = () => {
  const getInitialData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await Promise.all([{ test1: getTest1 }, { test2: getTest2 }, { test3: getTest3 }])

      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        const el = res[i]
        console.log(' ~ el', el)
      }

      const test1 = await res[0].test1
      const test2 = await res[1].test2
      const test3 = await res[2].test3

      test1.isError && console.log('Error in test1', test1.isError)
      test2.isError && console.log('Error in test2', test2.isError)
      test3.isError && console.log('Error in test3', test3.isError)

      const state = {
        test1: test1.isData,
        test2: test2.isData,
        test3: test3.isData,
      }
      console.log(' ~ state', state)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(' ~ Error', error)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialData()
  }, [getInitialData])

  return <div>PromiseAll</div>
}
```

Example here with console.log `Object { test3: Promise { "fulfilled" } }` in loop https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-mendel-xm5jk9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Please make your runnable example **here, on-site**, not just offsite. When you do it offsite, it's far too easy to leave out important code here on-site, and besides, people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you (and some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future). Instead, make a [mre] using Stack Snippets. They support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Your `Promise.all` doesn't even work. You need to pass an array of promises, not an array of objects (containing promises). Your actual waiting happens in the `const test1 = await res[0].test1;` line - which you could (and should) just have written as `const test1 = await getTest1;`.

Comment: Why are you storing 3 promises in global variables? Don't do that, they might not get error handlers attached to them and crash you app. Did you mean to declare functions that return promises?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*how can i make it generate it's own error and storing data to state object, instead of my manually adding those values?*".

Comment: Bergi all this storing is just example to get data when there is data and throw error hen i need to, it works in production fine and as expected. I just don't want manually keep creating new store object or error handler when new api is being added to promise.all

Comment: Bergi i'm passing them as objects in promise.all because i want to keep track of what object is for what api call. then use that tracking to display error message for that specific call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like

```
async function awaitNamedPromises(nameToPromise) {
  const namesAndPromises = Object.entries(nameToPromise);
  const promises = namesAndPromises.map(([, promise]) => promise);
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  return Object.fromEntries(namesAndPromises.map(([name, promise], index) => [name, results[index]]));
}

const results = await awaitNamedPromises({
  test1: Promise.resolve('hello'),
  test2: Promise.resolve('world'),
  test3: Promise.resolve('bye'),
});

console.log(results);
```

This prints out

```
{ test1: 'hello', test2: 'world', test3: 'bye' }
```

Comment: similar i dont before but your looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating outside object with it's name but only passing Promise only to Promise.all this is rough prototype.

```
  const getInitialData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const api = [
        { name: 'test1', api: getTest1 },
        { name: 'test2', api: getTest2 },
        { name: 'test3', api: getTest3 },
      ]

      const res = await Promise.all(api.map((el) => el.api))

      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        const el = res[i]

        el.isError && console.log(`Error in ${api[i].name}`, el.isError)

        const state = { [api[i].name]: el.isData }

        console.log(' ~ state', state)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(' ~ Error', error)
    }
  }, [])
```

Offcourse i would use something prevState on `state` so the previous data won't be overridden on each loop